# How i can initialize checkbox default model to false inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The default value for `item.selected` value is `undefined`.
The value turned to `true` or `false` when user interact.

**My question** -  How i can initialize `selected` default to `false` for each `item` inside `ng-repeat`?

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in students">
    <td width="5%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.selected" data-ng-change="changeHandler()" />
        <label for="inv{{$index}}"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `data-ng-init="item.selected=false"`

Answer (score 0):

Using **data-ng-init** will most definitely be the right choice.

Otherwise, you can loop through and set selected to false.

```
$scope.students.forEach(function(item){ item.selected = false;})
```

Have a look at the plunker I have created:
https://plnkr.co/edit/B58eErOvs6tU7G7z7Bv1